# Undefined offset error in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I got this messege when I run the code below
Notice: Undefined offset: 226 in C:\wamp\www\cbir\index.php on line 50

I think that these lines of code cause the error
         $reds[$r]++;
         $greens[$g]++;
         $blues[$b]++;

```
    $reds = array();

    $blues = array();
    $greens = array();

    $freqr = array();
    $freqb = array();
    $freqg = array();

    $info = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    $width = $info[0];
    $height = $info[1];
    $totalpixels = $width * $height;

    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if ($img) {
         for ($i = 0; $i < $height; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $width; $j++) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $j, $i);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

            // Add counts to our histogram arrays for each color.
            $reds[$r]++;
            $greens[$g]++;
            $blues[$b]++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your line 50?

Comment: this is my line 50 $reds[$r]++;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialized an empty array of `$reds`, but didn't define `$reds[$r]` (for example). 
Instead of :

```
$reds[$r]++;
```

Use:

```
if(!isset($reds[$r])) {
  $reds[$r] = 0;
}
$reds[$r]++;
```

Similar for `$greens` and `$blues`.

Alternatively, as the keys that will be used are from 0 to 255, you can first initialized the array using:

```
$reds = array_fill(0, 256, 0); // instead of using: $reds = array();
```